# How do I create an int that other classes can see and edit? Android

Tags: android, class

I have a class called Scouting, and it runs a function in a different class ScoutingFormData(different java file in the same package). I want it so that an integer defined in Scouting can be edited from ScoutingFormData. I defined the int:`public int SFID=-1;` in the main class of Scouting, but I can't figure out how to edit that int from ScoutingFormData.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't make your instance fields public, use getter and setters.

```
public int getField() {
    return field;
}
public void setField(int field) {
    this.field = field;
}
```

This is if your field needs to be an instance field.

If you need a field that belongs to the class `ScoutingObject` you need to make it static

```
public static int SFID=-1;
```

Then you can access it like this:

```
ScoutingObject.SFID
```

Answer (score 2):

add `static` modifer to it so it belongs to the class.

If you mean objectwise. Use getters and setters.

Or you can change it directly by doing `ScoutingObject.SFID=?; //in your ScoutingFormData class.`

Answer (score -1):

Use getters and setters and avoid using public attributes.

Make these methods in your *Scouting class*:

```
public int getMyInteger() 
{
  return myInteger;
}

public void setMyInteger(int newIntegerValue) 
{
  this.myInteger = newIntegerValue;
}
```

Where you have your private int myInteger.

In your *ScoutingFormData class* your can get and set the values:

```
setMyInteger(23); // The integer myInteger in the Scouting class is now set to 23

int newInteger = getMyInteger(); // The integer newInteger has been initialized to myIntegers value
```